# How to bind to a dependency property with an unknown type

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a user control that has a dependency property that I need to bind with multiple types. In other words, it has a dependency property named "DataSource." However, the developer could bind a type

```
ObservableCollection<MyCustomType>
```

or

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MyCustomType>>.
```

In the user control's code, I want to execute two separate code chunks based on which type is detected as not null or something equivalent. I've been searching for examples but I think my perspective on how this should be done may be misplaced. Instruction or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I have provided an answer, however I am wondering what different functionality your control is going to provide? Perhaps the use of an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate` of your custom control would be a better approach for when using the second type of datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your dependency property as a property of type `object`.

Then when the value of this property changes, you can perform different functionality depending upon the value of it, i.e.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("DataSource", typeof(object), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetaData(OnDataSourceChanged));

private static void OnDataSourceChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newValue = e.NewValue;

    if(newValue == null)
        return;

    var asSingleLevel = newValue as ObservableCollection<MyCustomType>;
    if(asSingleLevel != null)
    {
        // Do work for single level
    }
    else
    {
        var asDoubleLevel = newValue as ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MyCustomType>>;

        if(asDoubleLevel != null)
        {
            // Do work for double level
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I had talked this over with another developer at work and considered this route but wasn't sure I could make it work. There was a lot of code to write based on this working so I didn't want to assume it was valid. I just got done implementing it though and it worked great. Thanks a lot.